# Tensorflow installation not working on Raspbian strech virtualbox

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, debian-stretch

I created a virtualbox with raspbian strech to help me develop using Tensorflow .

pip install tensorflow installs successfully, but when importing tensorflow an error occurs.

> > > import tensorflow
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 23, in 
> > >           from tensorflow.python import *
> > >         File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
> > >           from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
> > >         File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
> > >           _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
> > >         File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > >           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
> > >         File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
> > >           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > >         File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
> > >           return _load(spec)
> > >       ImportError: /home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

building Tensorflow wheel from source didnt work for me ,